# getting sum and difference of a column value, multiple trigger

Tags: mysql

I have five columns namely

- first_payment
- second_payment
- total_fee
- total_payment
- student_balance

I want to add the value of first and second payment and insert the answer inside the total_payment column.
the total_fee column has a default value and i want to get the difference of total_payment and total_fee and insert it inside the student_balance.

I already have a code at adding 
here it is

```
USE `sample`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `new_table_BINS` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `new_table` 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.total_payment = NEW.first_payment + NEW.second_payment
```

But I'm trying to create another `trigger` but it didn't work
here it is

```
USE `sample`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `new_table_BINS1` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `new_table` 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.student_balance = NEW.total_fee + NEW.total_payment
```

it said that the program doesn't support multiple trigger but i really need the code for getting the difference.

I'm using Mysql workbench 6.1.7

can you help me???

Comment: why dont you add the 2nd trigger logic in the first trigger as well. This will solve the issue.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty it can't...can you show me how to add it in the first trigger???

Comment: why not just add the following `SET NEW.student_balance = NEW.total_fee + NEW.total_payment ;` in the first trigger

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i've tried it...it can't

Comment: Not sure why it can't, could you give some example data along with the data to be inserted.

Comment: total_fee has a default value of 20,000. first_payment and second_payment are inserted by the user. the total_payment is the sum of first_payment and second_payment. i want to get the difference of total_fee and total_payment and to be inserted at student_balance.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i've already figured it out...thank you very much

Comment: If your db server is on the same box as workbench you should be able to drop the trigger and create a new one.